# RuntimeError: Graph ops missing from the python registry ({'SentencepieceEncodeSparse'}) are also absent from the c++ registry

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to use `sentecepiece` in the Windows system while implementing universal sentence encoder as [described](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-xling-many/1) in tensorflow.

But I am getting below error:

> RuntimeError: Graph ops missing from the python registry
>   ({'SentencepieceEncodeSparse'}) are also absent from the c++ registry.

I know [this](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/issues/178) library has been supported now:

I tried installing `sentencepiece` using 
`pip install --user sentencepiece`
with many versions too. I can import `sentencepiece`, but get an error
`RuntimeError: Graph ops missing from the python registry ({'SentencepieceEncodeSparse'})` are also absent from the C++ registry.

I also tried conda install `tf_sentencepiece`, but it throws an error:
`anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf_sentencepiece\_sentencepiece_processor_ops`. So it is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.

---

```
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-956b40af1330> in <module>
----> 1 import tf_sentencepiece

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf_sentencepiece\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 from tf_sentencepiece.sentencepiece_processor_ops import *

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf_sentencepiece\sentencepiece_processor_ops.py in <module>
     25 
     26 _gen_sentencepiece_processor_op = tf.load_op_library(
---> 27     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so'))
     28 
     29 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py in load_op_library(library_filename)
     59     RuntimeError: when unable to load the library or get the python wrappers.
     60   """
---> 61   lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
     62 
     63   op_list_str = py_tf.TF_GetOpList(lib_handle)

NotFoundError: C:\Users\AUSER\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf_sentencepiece\_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to downgrade your TensorFlow version to 1.13.1.
You can see that on google's github page:
https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/tree/master/tensorflow/tf_sentencepiece

(look at the description)

Comment: Hi Michel, Thanks for replying.
But I already have tf 1.13.1 version installed. On colab it is working like butter with any version you install, but on windows it isn't.

Comment: C:\Users\ashwini\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py", line 61, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)

NotFoundError: C:\Users\veas9001\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tf_sentencepiece\_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so not found

--------------------------------------------------------
Despite of file "_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so" being at required location, it gives NotFoundError.